# Cloudera Manager Installation - Cant find hosts (single node)

Tags: cloudera, cloudera-manager

I am trying to just install the whole thing (manager, single node cluster) on a single RedHat box for evaluation.  I don't want to use the VM for now.

I am assuming you can simply install everything on a single server should you wish to (I may be wrong).

When I am in the wizard though, and I enter the FQDN of the host which is running the Cloudera Manager installations, it just hangs.

[image]

Comment: What happens when you ssh to that host from a shell?

Comment: I am able to ssh in via MobaXTerm, that’s how I installed Cloudera Manager to initiate the wizard

Comment: That's not what I meant.  When you run ssh using exactly the same command as Cloudera Manager would, are you able to ssh in?

Comment: How do I know how it is trying to ssh in?

Comment: you are providing the hostname in the UI.

Comment: @smackenzie - Are you able to run `ssh root@<hostname>` on a terminal?